# Complex Nested If, AND, Or Function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I must admit, I am not a trained Excel user but I am trying to learn it via the online resources such as yours. Here's the problem I am hoping to solve in Excel.

I have two columns with text values in 9 rows each, say A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L, (Column A), and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (Column B). There are multiple combinations, `A AND 1` gives `High` result, Or `A AND 7` gives `Low` result. Up to this point, I have no problem with this statement:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1="A",B1="1"),AND(A1="A",C2="7")),"High","Low")
```

1. However, there is a possibility that Neither A AND 1 or A AND 7 come into the picture. And when this does not happen, I would like it leave the cell blank.
2. Another complexity is that I want to nest more arguments, such as

   ```
   =IF(OR(AND(A1="B",B1="2"),AND(A1="B",C2="8")),"High","Low") 
   =IF(OR(AND(A1="C",B1="3"),AND(A1="C",C2="9")),"High","Low")
   =IF(OR(AND(A1="D",B1="4"),AND(A1="D",C2="10")),"High","Low")
   =IF(OR(AND(A1="E",B1="5"),AND(A1="E",C2="11")),"High","Low")
   =IF(OR(AND(A1="F",B1="6"),AND(A1="F",C2="12")),"High","Low")
   =IF(OR(AND(A1="G",B1="7"),AND(A1="G",C2="1")),"High","Low")
   ```

and so on.

What would be the most efficient solution to this?

Comment: Are the values actually letters or is that just an example, if so the first half of your equation could be "=IF(COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1 & 1))<>B1,"High", "Low")" for example. An example of what the actual data will look like may help if this is not the case.

Comment: Create separate table (for example on hidden service sheet) which stores concatenated columns combination and the value which matches this combination (i.e. 'A1'-'High', 'A7'-'Low', 'B2'-'High', 'B8'-'Low' and so on). Then use VLOOKUP(Ax&Bx,"ServiceSheet"!A:B,2) and receive according value for a combination (N/A may be converted to empty string with proper function if needed).

Answer (score 0):

For the example data you have posted I think this formula works:

```
=IF(B1 = MOD(6 + MOD(COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1 & 1)),12),12),"High",IF(COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1 & 1))=B1,"Low",""))
```